# finding determinant as an function in given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate the determinant of the following matrix as an explicit
function of $x$. (It is a polynomial in $x$. You are asked to find
all the coefficients.)

\begin{bmatrix}1 & x & x^{2} & x^{3} & x^{4}\\
x^{5} & x^{6} & x^{7} & x^{8} & x^{9}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{10} & x^{11}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{12} & x^{13}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{14} & x^{15}
\end{bmatrix}

Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: matrix blocks $ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\ C & D\end{pmatrix} = \det\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\ 0 & D\end{pmatrix} = \det(A) \det(D)$$
Where $A,B,C,D$ are block matrices.

Comment: should I choose A as upperleft two rows and columns and D as lower right 3 rows and columns?

Comment: wait, I didn't even have to do anything. A that I chose has determinant of zero so the whole matrix will have determinant of zero right?

Comment: A is any $n$ by $n$ block on the top left. You can indeed choose $n=3$ and get zero as you stated.

Answer (score 6):

First, note that the 5th column is a multiple of the 4th column. That is,

\begin{bmatrix}
x^4\\
x^9\\
x^{11}\\
x^{13}\\
x^{15}\\
\end{bmatrix}

is $x$ times
\begin{bmatrix}
x^3\\
x^8\\
x^{10}\\
x^{12}\\
x^{14}\\
\end{bmatrix}.

Because the determinant of a matrix does not change when you subtract a multiple of one column from another column, we get that that matrix has the same determinant as that of

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & x^2 & x^3 & 0\\
x^5 & x^6 & x^7 & x^8 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{10} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{12} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{14} & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

and you can easily tell that the determinant of that matrix is $0$.

Comment: Now I see. This is a another great way to approach determinant. Thanks for the beautiful insight

Comment: Or, the determinant of a matrix in which its columns are linearly dependent is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this: the bottom three rows can't have rank more than $2$, since they have only two nonzero columns, so the whole matrix can't have rank more than $4$, and therefore is singular.